# Matrices product and homogeneous system solutions

Tags: linear-algebra

Given two matrices $A$ and $B$ both not equal to the zero matrix. $A$ is in the order of $m\times n$ and B is the order of $n\times m$ so the the product $AB$ is valid. Also given is that $AB=0$. Will the homogeneous system $Bx=0$ necessarily have a non trivial solution? If so, can it be proven? If not, is there a good counter example?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, we cannot conclude that $B$ has a nontrivial nullspace. For example, take $B=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and $A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\end{smallmatrix}\right).$

In general, how do we think about a question like this?

A matrix has a trivial kernel if it is injective, as a map of vectors. A matrix has full rank if it is surjective, as a map of vectors. And in general, there are two conclusions we can draw about the surjectivity or injectivity of a product $AB.$ First, if $A$ does not hit every vector, then $AB$ cannot either. Secondly, if $B$ kills some vector, then $AB$ must kill it too. By contraposition: $AB$ surjective implies $A$ surjective, and $AB$ injective implies $B$ injective. Both statements are obvious if you think intuitively about the picture of a function (insert picture here).

But your question is (by contraposition): does $B$ injective imply $AB$ injective? It's not one of the two valid conclusions of this type that I listed above, so I think the answer is "no". And using the intuitive picture of functions, I can easily construct a counter example. Let $B$ be an injection of a smaller space into a larger. Then let $A$ be something whose kernel is the image of $A$. Then $Bx=0$ will have no nontrivial solutions, but $AB=0$ will still hold.

Then I choose a basis for these spaces and write the matrices.

Comment: But B is not n x m. maybe if you had a B that is also 3 x 3 like A

Comment: @eventhorizon02 oh you're right. I failed to notice that the codomain of $A$ is the domain of $B$. I'm sorry. My answer is incorrect, I shall edit.

Comment: @eventhorizon02 ok better.

Comment: Looks good, thank you very much!

Comment: @eventhorizon02 but note that we could not find counterexamples that are square matrices. If a square matrix is injective, then it is also surjective, hence invertible. Then $AB=0$ implies $A=B=0.$